# How do I remove an image from a PushButton in guizero?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter

I want to be able to remove an image (assigned at instantiation or later with .image property) from a PushButton and make it look back to its native look?

Though the documentation says the default value for the .image property is `None`, if I try to set it to `None` I get an error code essentially telling me that the image is not found or not of the right format.
Same if I try to set it to null string ("")

```
from guizero import App, PushButton

app = App()
button = PushButton(app, image = "button.gif")
button.image = None  # <-- This line generates the error

app.display()
```

*** GUIZERO ERROR ***
Image import error - 'Image must be a file path, PIL.Image or tkinter.PhotoImage'
Check the file path and image type is GIF/Animated GIF/BMP/ICO/PNG/JPG/TIF

Comment: Try `button.tk.config(image="")`?

Comment: Thank you, it works! With one caveat: the button dimensions are out of whack (presumably because they used to refer to pixels and now they refer to characters.  
So, to fix it your code is slightly different:

`button.tk.config(width = 3, height = 1, image="")`
Though this means I cannot rely anymore on the width and height properties to be set automatically